# Detecting a play event in youtube api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, youtube, event-listener

I'm looking for a way to detect a play event in an embedded Youtube video via Javascript.  Right now I'm able to detect state change, but I can't figure out how to unbind the event after and fire another event saying that it's complete. I'd also prefer not to use add/removeEventListener because I guess IE8 and below don't have this function.

My code so far,

```
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    console.log('loaded');
    var ytPlayer = document.getElementById(playerId);
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    console.log("Player's new state: " + newState);
    if(newState === 1) {
        sendYtUrl();
     }
}

function sendYtUrl() {
    console.log('play detected');
    ytplayer.removeEventListener("onStateChange");
}
```

I'm hoping to pop into sendYtUrl, remove listener, then do whatever I need to do, or even better, keep it cleaner and leave it in the same function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to unbind the [`onStateChange` event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events) to know when the video ends or is completed. The `onStateChange` only needs to have one event listener. It will be fired and return the following states every time any of these situations occur:

```
-1 (unstarted)
0 (ended)
1 (playing)
2 (paused)
3 (buffering)
5 (video cued)
```

In your function `onytplayerStateChange`, add another `if` statement to catch when the video is complete:

```
function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    console.log("Player's new state: " + newState);
    if(newState === 1) {
        sendYtUrl();
    } else if(newState === 0) {
        console.log("Video has ended!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much! That bumped me in the right direction.

Here's what I ended up doing.

```
var ytPlaying = 0;
var ytPlayed = '';
var currPlaying = '';

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    //console.log('loaded');
    var ytPlayer = document.getElementById(playerId);
    ytPlayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    currPlaying = window.location.hash;
    //console.log("Player's new state: " + newState);
    if (newState === 1) {
        console.log('playing');
        clientSideTracking();
    }   
}


function clientSideTracking() {
   // console.log('client tracking');
    //console.log(currPlaying, ytPlayed);
    if (currPlaying != ytPlayed) { // if current playing isn't the same as prior played
        //console.log('different'); // then it's different - track it.
        var event = new AnalyticsPageEvent('Youtube Analytics', currPlaying);
        event.trigger();
    }
    ytPlaying = 0; // change back to 'not played' and change to 0 so that it's logged
    ytPlayed = currPlaying;

}
```

What it does is trigger the AnalyticPageEvent when there's a new URL that hasn't been played yet. :)

Comment: No problem, +1 for posting your solution!